# Cloud function for firestore onWrite

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I update or delete my document via firebase console my function triggered  but when I log the
field  `context.eventType` I'm getting `google.firestore.document.write` instead of  `google.firestore.document.delete` or `google.firestore.document.update`

Any clue please ?

Code:

```
exports.useTest = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onWrite(async (handle, context) => {
    console.log("before", handle.before.data());
    console.log("after", handle.after.data());
    console.log("eventType", context.eventType);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers), your Firestore functions will trigger the `onWrite` since it is triggered whether `onCreate`, `onUpdate` or `onDelete` is triggered. Regardless of the trigger, the `onWrite` will be shown.

There's also a guide to [trigger a function for all changes to a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document) that you can follow:

```
exports.modifyUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userID}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // Get an object with the current document value.
      // If the document does not exist, it has been deleted.
      const document = change.after.data();

      // Get an object with the previous document value (for update or delete)
      const oldDocument = change.before.data();

      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

For further reference, you can refer to these documentations:

1. [Trigger a function when a new document is created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created)
2. [Trigger a function when a document is updated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated)
3. [Trigger a function when a document is deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted)

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect `handle`:

```
if (!handle.before.exists && handle.after.exists) {
    // created
} else if (handle.before.exists && !handle.after.exists) {
    // deleted
} else {
    // updated
}
```